# Go heap.Interface as a struct

Tags: go

I'm creating a priority queue using Go's [heap](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/) package. There is [an example](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__priorityQueue) of one in the documentation.

The queue I'm creating needs to be based around a struct rather than a slice because it requires other properties like a mutex.

```
type PQueue struct {
    queue []*Item
    sync.Mutex
}
```

I implement all the methods that [heap.Interface](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#Interface) requires.

The issue is that my `PQueue.Push` method seems not to be permanently adding a value to `PQueue.queue`.

```
func (p PQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.place = len(p.queue) // the index of an item in the queue
    p.queue = append(p.queue, item)
    // len(p.queue) does increase
    // after the functions exits, the queues length has not increased
}
```

If I print the length of `p.queue` at the end of this function, the length has increased. After the functions exits however, it seems the original struct does not get updated.

I think it might be happening because of `func (p PQueue)` not being a pointer. Why might that be? Is there a way to fix it? If I were to use `func (p *PQeueue) Push(x interface{})` instead, I would need to implement my own heap because `heap.Interface` specifically requires no pointer. Is that my only option?

Comment: Nah, `heap.Interface` doesn't require no pointer. Pointer types can implement an interface (`*os.File` is an `io.Reader`). Try it, and if it doesn't work in a way that you can't figure out, post another question; someone'll try to help sort it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the problem being related to the receiver of your `Push` method: the method will receive a copy of the `PQueue`, so any changes made to the struct will not persist.

Changing the method to use a pointer as a receiver is the correct change, but this also means that `PQueue` no longer implements `heap.Interface`.  This is due to the fact that Go does not let you take a pointer to the value stored inside an interface variable, so the automatic translation of `q.Push()` to `(&q).Push()` does not occur.

This isn't a dead end though, since `*PQueue` should still implement the `heap.Interface`.  So if you were previously calling `heap.Init(q)`, just change it to `heap.Init(&q)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are appending to a **copy** of your slice. Thus the change shows within the function, but is lost once you return from the function.

In [this blog article](http://blog.golang.org/slices) from the section **Passing slices to functions**:

> It's important to understand that even though a slice contains a
>   pointer, it is itself a value. Under the covers, it is a struct value
>   holding a pointer and a length. It is not a pointer to a struct.

With append you are modifying the slice header. And

> Thus if we want to write a function that modifies the header, we must
>   return it as a result parameter

Or:

> Another way to have a function modify the slice header is to pass a
>   pointer to it.

As a result you need to pass a pointer if you want to modify it with append. Simply change the method to use a pointer receiver. And for that to work you need to call init with a pointer like `heap.Init(&pq)` as shown in the example that you linked to which does just that and also uses pointer receivers.

From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) on **Method Sets**:

> The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods 
>   declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of T).

So using a pointer type will work with value and pointer receivers and still implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it might be happening because of func (p PQueue) not being a pointer

That's right. Quoting [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values):

> invoking [the method] on a value would cause the method to receive a
>   copy of the value, so any modifications would be discarded.

You say:

> heap.Interface specifically requires no pointer

I'm confused, the example you point to is, in fact, using a pointer:

```
func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    n := len(*pq)
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    *pq = append(*pq, item)
}
```

Maybe something else is going on?